# Accidentally formatting videos

Tags: c, video, format, output

### Context

Today I was editing videos for my future uploads. I spent half of my day editing in CapCut. Sadly I made wrong name for the output file so the videos where separated inside subfolder. So what I got is 24 videos with same name inside different folders. Then I thought I could try to make a code to move all files from subfolders to the right folder..

### What happened

So I came up with this code and it made all files disappear. Mosty trying to consult with artificial inteligence. Following thing is very bad and I hope we can somehow patiently get to the right output. So I thought this code will just move files. Unfortunately all files were formatted into all sorts of files. .ini, .crc, .meta, .string, .model, .jpg, .ini, .extra, .png, .html, .js, .css, .meta, .lua.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void moveFiles(const char *sourceDir, const char *destDir) {
    DIR *dir = opendir(sourceDir);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening source directory");
        return;
    }

    struct dirent *entry;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0) {
            char srcPath[256];
            snprintf(srcPath, sizeof(srcPath), "%s/%s", sourceDir, entry->d_name);

            struct stat fileStat;
            if (stat(srcPath, &fileStat) == 0) {
                if (S_ISREG(fileStat.st_mode)) {
                    char destPath[256];
                    snprintf(destPath, sizeof(destPath), "%s/%s", destDir, entry->d_name);
                    if (rename(srcPath, destPath) != 0) {
                        perror("Error moving file");
                    }
                } else if (S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) {
                    char subdir[256];
                    snprintf(subdir, sizeof(subdir), "%s/%s", sourceDir, entry->d_name);
                    moveFiles(subdir, destDir);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}

int main() {
    // Get the user's home directory
    const char *homedir;
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(geteuid());
    if (pw != NULL) {
        homedir = pw->pw_dir;
    } else {
        perror("Error getting home directory");
        return 1;
    }

    // Append "Movies" directory to the home directory path
    char moviesDir[256];  // Assuming the directory path won't exceed 256 characters
    snprintf(moviesDir, sizeof(moviesDir), "%s/Movies", homedir);

    // Move files from subdirectories to the "Movies" directory
    moveFiles(moviesDir, moviesDir);

    printf("Files from subdirectories moved to the 'Movies' directory.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Are my videos gone or is there way to get them back please ?

### Update

When I want open folder from searching browser, for example YouTube, It keeps all the videos with original format and I can upload as nothing happened. Does viewing the files from browser have any influence to see these files in .mov format ?

Comment: As `snprintf()` may fail (not a large enough buffer), why does code not check the `snprintf()` return value?  Further, I'd recommend a failure to cause the operation to stop, rather than continue.

Comment: Tip: rather than making a 256 buffer at each level, make one 4k buffer at the top and pass it and the length used into `moveFiles()`.

Comment: `moveFiles(moviesDir, moviesDir);` --> Really the intent to move files from A to A?

Comment: I'm sorry, unfortunately, some files may be lost. _So what I got is 24 videos with **same** name inside different folders_ To me, this says your original hierarchy was (e.g.) `Movies/dirX/fileA` and `Movies/dirY/fileA` Your program will move both of these files to `Movies/fileA`, so one of them will be lost. I wrote a script that generated a random hierarchy of files with the same names in various subdirs. I ran your program on it. I started with 113 files but after your program ran, I had only 49 remaining

Comment: Your program does move all flat files from any and all subdirs into the top directory (it will leave the [empty] subdirs). So, AFAICT, whatever files you have left are directly under `Movies`. Under POSIX/linux, there may be nothing that can be done. But, in your program, names where limited to 256 chars. This is a windows limitation. So, are you using Windows? They added some sort of file history to each file in lieu of image backup https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-file-history-in-windows-11.1395/

Comment: Hi guys, quick update: I want to say that when I click on update video on YouTube then what pops up is finder where I choose the folder movies, all videos are shown in this folder. Yes I have Mac. So what Is my next question to ask how is that happening? is it finder have them somehow saved or youtube have compressed these formats together somehow?

Comment: @Justin You need to use **@** symbol to notify anyone. Usually the first-responder gets automatic updates about new comments (replies), but once you have multiple people in comments, then no-one is auto-updated without you using a `@name` tagging for them.

Comment: @Justin PS:  **(1)** I don't have a Mac but I can tell you a website (_eg:_ Youtube) cannot put files on your hard drive without you clicking to save them. **(2)** Not clear what you've got inside Movies folder (is it other multiple sub-folders? or is it just one folder listing many MP4 files in that one place?). **(3)** Since you've now re-found these files, what do you need to do with them? Join them as one MP4 file? or is it something else?

Comment: Im sorry, I've found out that the original files were fine, I just didn't knew they were there because the program created so many new files I lost truck of them.. I apologise for the rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple answer

Simply try code in different subdirectories. What you will find out that the program is working perfectly to your needs. What happened is that your videos were moved but also compromised into different formats. The list of files that were created was so long you lost track what was in the folder..

### Assurance that Videos are Fine:

Since you mentioned being able to view the videos in their original format when accessed via a browser like YouTube, it indicates that the videos are not lost or corrupted. This is a positive sign.

### Try in Different Subdirectories:

It might be beneficial to attempt moving files from different subdirectories to ensure the process works as intended. This involves adjusting the source subdirectory and destination directory paths in the code and rerunning it.

### Try this solution:

```
void moveFiles(const char *sourceDir, const char *destDir) {
    DIR *dir = opendir(sourceDir);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening source directory");
        return;
    }

    struct dirent *entry;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0) {
            char srcPath[256];
            snprintf(srcPath, sizeof(srcPath), "%s/%s", sourceDir, entry->d_name);

            struct stat fileStat;
            if (stat(srcPath, &fileStat) == 0) {
                if (S_ISREG(fileStat.st_mode)) {
                    if (strstr(entry->d_name, ".str") != NULL) {
                        // Skip .str files and remove them instead of moving
                        if (remove(srcPath) != 0) {
                            perror("Error removing .str file");
                        }
                    } else {
                        char destPath[256];
                        snprintf(destPath, sizeof(destPath), "%s/%s", destDir, entry->d_name);
                        if (rename(srcPath, destPath) != 0) {
                            perror("Error moving file");
                        }
                    }
                } else if (S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) {
                    moveFiles(srcPath, destDir);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

in the main function is easier.

```c
    const char *sourceSubDir = "/Path/to/subdirectories"; // Source subdirectory
    const char *destDir = "/Path/to/destination/directory"; // Destination directory
    
    moveFiles(sourceSubDir, destDir);
```